# How to translate a SQL to Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I transform this current `sql` statement into Eloquent and have results grouped by `team_id` inside a grouped by `group_id`?

```
SELECT 
    max(`group_id`) as group_id,
    `team_id` as team_id, 
    max(level_id) as level_id, 
    sum(`played`) as played,
    sum(`won`) as won,
    sum(`draw`) as draw,
    sum(`lost`) as lost,
    sum(`gf`) as gf,
    sum(`ga`) as ga,
    sum(`gd`) as gd,
    sum(`points`) as points 
FROM `group_team` 
WHERE level_id = 1 
GROUP BY team_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
$query= DB::table('group_team')
    ->max('group_id')
    ->where('level_id',1)
    ->groupBy('team_id')
    ->get();
```

Or you can run raw sql to query direct to db, like this

```
$query = DB::select('SELECT max("group_id") as group_id' FROM group_team WHERE level_id = 1 GROUP BY team_id);
```

For a better explanation, check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Answer (score 1):

my best try is:

knowing that GroupTeam is your Model

```
GroupTeam::where('level_id', 1)
    ->groupBy('team_id')
    ->addSelect(
        DB::raw('*, 
            max(`group_id`) as group_id,
            `team_id` as team_id, 
            max(level_id) as level_id, 
            sum(`played`) as played,
            sum(`won`) as won,
            sum(`draw`) as draw,
            sum(`lost`) as lost,
            sum(`gf`) as gf,
            sum(`ga`) as ga,
            sum(`gd`) as gd,
            sum(`points`) as points'
        )   
    )->get();

</code>
```